# How do I find N in geometric sequence nor series if the given are only the last term and the ratio?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

The question is: The last term of a geometric sequence is 625. If the common ratio is 1/3, how many terms does the sequence have?

Comment: $ar^{n-1} = 625$ where $r = \frac{1}{3}$. Obviously, in this equation, even after putting the value of r, there are two unknowns.So there can be any number of solutions. Fix one of them and solve for the other !

Comment: That doesn't sound like a sensible question. The first term can be as large as you want to make it, $(3^n)(625)$, where $n$ (which you're supposed to determine) can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: I still not get it. :(

Comment: the real observation you have to make is if the sequence has 1 term you fulfill the  requirements (625 and 1/3) if the sequence has 2 terms you can find the previous term, in general, you can assume it has any number of terms and it stills fulfill the conditions (625 and 1/3)

Comment: Therefore $N$ can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is not unique.
since
$$u_n=u_1 (1/3)^{n-1}=625$$

we can take

$$u_1=625 , n=1$$
or
$$u_1=1875, n=2... $$